# Check if two rectangles overlap

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Suppose rectangles are parallel to x-axis/y-axis. Check if two rectangles overlap or not and if they do, output the overlap area.

Here is my code and I track min/max x-coordinate and min/max y-coordinate for each rectangle. Using Python 2.7.

Any comments on code bugs, code style and performance improvements in terms of algorithm time complexity are appreciated.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y):
        self.min_x = min_x
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.min_y = min_y
        self.max_y = max_y

    def is_intersect(self, other):
        if self.min_x > other.max_x or self.max_x < other.min_x:
            return False
        if self.min_y > other.max_y or self.max_y < other.min_y:
            return False
        return True

    def get_insersec_region(self, other):
        if not self.is_intersect(other):
            return None
        min_x = max(self.min_x, other.min_x)
        max_x = min(self.max_x, other.max_x)
        min_y = max(self.min_y, other.min_y)
        max_y = min(self.max_y, other.max_y)

        return Rectangle(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.min_x) + '\t' + str(self.max_x) + '\t' + str(self.min_y) + '\t' + str(self.max_y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r1 = Rectangle(0,10,0,10)
    r2 = Rectangle(5,15,5,15)
    print r1.is_intersect(r2)
    print r1.get_insersec_region(r2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `insersec`? ;)

Comment: If you’re using Python 2.7, custom classes should subclass from `object`; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2588628/1558022 for more background. I’d also recommend adding a `__repr__` for easy debuggability.

Comment: @RolandIllig, means common area covered by both rectangles, if you have good ideas of my original question, it will be great.

Comment: @alexwlchan, how `__repr` is making debugging easier? I found Pycharm IDE is much more helpful. :)

Comment: @LinMa what I really wanted to ask is: why do you write `insersec` (2 typos) when the correct spelling is `intersect`?

Comment: @RolandIllig, oh! Yes, I am correcting it. Thanks for pointing out. If you have any comments and ideas on my original question, it will be great. :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, sorry for the confusion. I know this rule and I just correct two typos, I will take care next time. :)

Comment: The code can be made shorter/easier by recognizing that rectangles are characterized by two lines at right angles, and that two rectangles overlap if and only if the corresponding lines overlap.  By solving the much shorter problem of "do these lines overlap?" you can shorten the rectangle overlap code considerably.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't believe your first sentence is true. If the orthogonal lines overlap, the rectangles also overlap, that's easy. But the other way round is not guaranteed. Can you elaborate more on how these two lines are defined? Maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: @RolandIllig: A line segment is an ordered pair of numbers, `start` and `end`.  A rectangle r is a pair of line segments, call them `top` and `left`. Two rectangles `r1` and `r2` overlap iff `r1.top` overlaps `r2.top` and `r1.left` overlaps `r2.left`. So you only have to solve the problem on line segments.

Comment: You can also use Eric Lippert's approach to calculate areas.  The area of an overlapping pair of rectangles is equal to the product of the length of the overlap of the line segments.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the explanation, now I understand it. When you said “line” in your first comment I thought a line were two-dimensional, and overlapping would also be defined in two-dimensional space. But then, doesn't the above code use exactly this concept of overlapping lines, except that everything is written as inlined code?

Comment: @EricLippert, you transfer the rectangle overlap problem into line segment overlap problem, it is a great idea. But how do you resolve the problem of line segment overlap -- could you show your solution code?

Comment: @RolandIllig, if you know how to check if line segment overlap, could you share some solutions? My confusion is, the top and left lines of two overlapped rectangles are in parallel, how do you check if they are overlap or not?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `get_insersec_region`, I would call this method `__and__`. This way you can use `overlap = r1 & r2`, just like for set intersection.

You can add `intersect = __and__` if you also want the expressiveness of `overlap = r1.intersect(r2)`.

Instead of returning `None`, I would consider returning an empty `Rectangle`. This way you don't need any special code to handle e.g. `(r1&r2).area`. For this, I would set default values for the coordinates, all `0`.

Incidentally, I would add an area method and make it a property:

```
@property
def area(self):
    return (self.max_x - self.min_x) * (self.max_y - self.min_y)
```

The reason it should be a property is maintainability. If you decide at some point that you only want to compute the area at creation time because a Rectangle is not allowed to change size anymore, you could remove this function and just store `self.area = ...` in the constructor. Also it is evidently true that the area of a rectangle is a property of that particular rectangle.

And an `__or__` method to get the bounding rectangle. You might need this if you want a GUI and update only the region where things changed but still want to do only one update. Then you need to find a rectangular area which includes all objects, which you can then just get by `|`ing all rectangles.

Your `__str__` method can be simplified using `map` and `str.join`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\t'.join(map(str, (self.min_x, self.max_x, self.min_y, self.max_y)))
```

Alternatively, you can use `str.format`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{self.min_x}\t{self.max_x}\t{self.min_y}\t{self.max_y}'.format(self=self)
```

The latter slightly more future proof, because you can replace it with this in Python 3.6, using f-strings:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.min_x}\t{self.max_x}\t{self.min_y}\t{self.max_y}'
```

**Final code**:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, min_x=0, max_x=0, min_y=0, max_y=0):
        self.min_x = min_x
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.min_y = min_y
        self.max_y = max_y

    def is_intersect(self, other):
        if self.min_x > other.max_x or self.max_x < other.min_x:
            return False
        if self.min_y > other.max_y or self.max_y < other.min_y:
            return False
        return True

    def __and__(self, other):
        if not self.is_intersect(other):
            return Rectangle()
        min_x = max(self.min_x, other.min_x)
        max_x = min(self.max_x, other.max_x)
        min_y = max(self.min_y, other.min_y)
        max_y = min(self.max_y, other.max_y)
        return Rectangle(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y)

    intersect = __and__

    def __or__(self, other):
        min_x = min(self.min_x, other.min_x)
        max_x = max(self.max_x, other.max_x)
        min_y = min(self.min_y, other.min_y)
        max_y = max(self.max_y, other.max_y)
        return Rectangle(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y)

    union = __or__

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Rectangle({self.min_x},{self.max_x},{self.min_y},{self.max_y})'.format(self=self)

    @property
    def area(self):
        return (self.max_x - self.min_x) * (self.max_y - self.min_y)
```

Comment: Thanks Graipher, love all of your comments, however have two different options, (1) your implementation of `or` has issues, suppose two rectangles do not overlap at all, return `or` of them is unclear what it means (in your implementation, your returned areas of `or` will contain area not in ether rectangle if they are not overlapping) (2) what is the benefit of making it a property in my problem?

Comment: @LinMa Yes, `__or__` is not a very clear concept. It returns a rectangle which bounds the two rectangles. You would need this if you want a GUI and update only the region where things changed but still want to do o Lynn one update. Then you need to find a rectangular area which includes all objects. You probably don't need it.

Comment: @LinMa it is a property for maintainability. If you decide at some point that you only want to compute the area at creation time because a Rectangle is not allowed to change size, you could remove this function and just store `self.area = ...` in the constructor. In your particular problem I don't know if this has any advantage. But that is due to the fact that you did not tell us about the problem these Rectangles are supposed to solve.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, your comments making it clear. Do you think there might be a more efficient solution to check if rectangle overlap? More efficient I mean from algorithm time complexity perspective.